# custom shutdown script in rc6.d does not seem to be working.

Tags: bash, shell-script, rhel, reboot

I'm working with a software application that's a bit touchy so I wan't to shut the software down automatically on reboot or shutdown. I have created a script an placed it in /etc/init.d/ with a symlink in /etc/rc6.d and named it "K99_restofname". The script works great testing it outside of a reboot scenario. The process takes close to a minute to do its work. I do not think its being ran or working when I reboot because the system shuts down way to fast and I should see a delay while the script works. (I'm also watching the screen) I also do not see anything in the logs. Here is my script:

```
 #!/bin/bash

## # Any subsequent(*) commands which fail will cause the shell     script to exit immediately

abort()
{
echo >&2 '
***************
*** ABORTED ***
***************
'
echo "An error occurred. Exiting..." >&2
exit 1
}

trap 'abort' 0

set -e

## Stopping the application services before the system shuts down. This   must be done by the application user user. 

VAR=`/bin/su -c "/opt/app/bin/command stopall" - user`

echo $VAR

# DONE

trap : 0

echo >&2 '
************
*** DONE *** 
************
'
```

Can anyone tell me what might be going on or how I can track down custom shutdown scripts? Is there a better way to accomplish my goal than this? My system is RHEL 6 server.

Answer (score 0):

Change the K99 to S00_ or mv S01reboot Sxxreboot and make your script S01.

What I did was to create a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Ran S10" >> /var/tmp/done
```

and called it "S10Test"

then another:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Ran K10" >> /var/tmp/done
```

Then I rebooted my VM.

/var/tmp/done contained "S10"

You may want to test yourself.

What I suspect is happening is that the S scripts run *as you enter* the runlevel. The K scripts run *as you leave*. Since S01Reboot (original name) does a reboot there is no "leave".

(note "suspect").

Comment: I've since added chkconfig params to my script with the following: chkconfig: 12345 91 06. I also have corresponding files in all rc.d locations. S91 links in rc1-5, and K06 links in rc0/6. Still not working on shutdown. Startup works fine.

Comment: That is because the S scripts run as you ENTER the runlevel and the K scripts run as you LEAVE the runlevel. 

You never LEAVE runlevel 6 because S01reboot rebooted.